# geojson to Elasticsearch : Unable to Tessellate shape

Tags: python, elasticsearch, geojson, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I am indexing some geojson file (around 4000 ~ 5000 multi-polygon features) into Elasticsearch.

Here is the mappings

```
"mappings": {
       "properties": {
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "properties": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "geo_shape"
      }
       }
    }
```

My code for indexing looks like this:

```
helpers.bulk(es, k, chunk_size=500, request_timeout=1000)
```

The indexing action (in chunk) is stopped by this error message:

```
{'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'failed to parse field [geometry] of type [geo_shape]', 'caused_by': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Unable to Tessellate shape
```

What is the cause of this error?
Can I ignore this error when indexing geojson files?

Comment: Can you show your index mapping as well as one JSON document from your bulk file that causes this issue?

Comment: @Val added in the post

Comment: ...  as well as one JSON document from your bulk file

Comment: @Val Sorry but I can't share JSON document.

Comment: Help us help you :-)

Comment: @Val can you share me with your email address? I can send you one JSON docs reported as error

Comment: I mean it's just a shape, don't share the properties field just the geometry and type ones.

Comment: @Val yes, I have several shapes (multi-polygons) which cause indexing errors. However, they are all too long to be posted here in comments :( Happy to share via email if it suits you

Comment: Try gist.github.com

Comment: @Val created, did u see it?

Comment: You need to share the URL

Comment: @Val there u go https://gist.github.com/Socrpion21/8fe1f74549890f1eb2dc7cb7ee0c1ee4

Comment: This usually happens when 1) shapes are self-intersecting or 2) they are not specified in counter-clock wise direction or 3) the start and end point are not the same. In your case, it is self-intersecting at different locations and you can see it in joe's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your geojson is syntactically correct & valid. Now you just need to make sure that you index your multi-polygons properly:

```
PUT demo_l08_bs
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "geo_shape"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index the geojson w/o changing anything:

```
POST demo_l08_bs/_doc
{
  "properties": {
    ...
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [...]
  }
}
```

Verify a point lies within it:

```
GET demo_l08_bs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "geometry": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "point",
          "coordinates": [
            151.14646911621094,
            -33.68463933764522
          ]
        },
        "relation": "intersects"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can manually index this single doc, however, I want to know how to handle it via python elasticsearch helpers.bulk

Comment: The problem with the shape is the fact that it is self-intersecting in many different places and ES doesn't allow that.

Comment: thanks @val -- 7.2.0 ingested it w/o an issue. 
@Scorpioooooon21 there are already answered q's regarding `helpers.bulk` such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/61642184/8160318 What ES version are you using?

Comment: Worth noting that on 7.6 and up I get the same issue as @Scorpioooooon21, i.e. `Unable to Tessellate shape`

Comment: You can see this thread for more background info on a similar issue I encountered a while ago and self-intersection was the culprit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587629/failed-to-create-valid-geo-shape/55588509#55588509

Comment: @Val, thanks for your comment. I use QGIS to valid all my polygons and none of them have self-intersection. Is there any recommended solution from you to quickly identify the polygons which are having self-intersection?

Comment: @Val I try to tune the "chunk_size" in helpers.bulk to 300, 400, 500, and each time I have various numbers of document ingested. Could this "Unable to Tessellate shape" issue caused by inappropriate chunk_size?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit @joe's image and you can see the little red circle at the top. If you zoom in on QGIS, you'll see that the points step on each other. That's what I mean by self intersection. QGIS (and the GeoJSON spec) are more permissible than ES.

Comment: For verifying CCW correctness, you can check this: https://mapster.me/right-hand-rule-geojson-fixer. Also I was successful in fixing self-intersections using this: https://github.com/mclaeysb/simplepolygon

Answer (score 4):

I had a look into the issue and the polygon is valid and uncover a bug in Lucene tessellator. I opened an issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-9417

And the fix is here:

https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/pull/1614

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio Vera for following up. How do I apply the fix to my current platform?

Comment: The change has been committed in Lucene and it will be included in the next Lucene release (lucene branchn 8.6 was cut yesterday). I would expect the fix will be included in the next Elasticsearch release that depends on that Lucene release.

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVera I can see that fix is now on the ES 7.9 https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.9/buildSrc/version.properties#L2

Comment: Hi @IgnacioVera! I tried the Elastic Search 7.9.1 docker (docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.1) containing your fix. I still get the "unable to tessellate shape" errors for self-intersecting shapes, even ones without 'holes'. Is this the expected behaviour? Would it help if I open a separate issue?

Comment: If the polygons are invalid (e.g they has self-intersecting edges) then yes, it is expected. I think it would be better if we open a separate issue.

Comment: Hi @IgnacioVera, I opened a separate issue regarding indexing self-intersecting polygons. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this error was caused by some complicated multi-polygons in the input file.

However, after converted multi-ploygons into individual polygons inspired by the below post, I managed to ingest all shapes without any error :)

https://gist.github.com/mhweber/cf36bb4e09df9deee5eb54dc6be74d26