# How to handle self-intersecting GeoJson polygons in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, polygon, geojson, shapes

We are indexing geo-json polygons using the [shape](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shape.html) data type in Elastic Search. The polygons are provided to us from an external source.
When indexing, some of the polygons fail with the following message.

> "Unable to Tessellate shape [[12.775555, 61.54487] [12.797356,
> 61.53186] [12.795639, 61.549286] [12.832375, 61.54536] [12.775555, 61.54487] ]. Possible malformed shape detected."

We believe the issue is related to self-intersecting polygons. The polygons seem to be valid, according to e.g https://geojsonlint.com. Below is an example of a self-intersecting polygon:

```
{
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              12.775554656982422,
              61.54486837329203
            ],
            [
              12.797355651855469,
              61.53186079051699
            ],
            [
              12.795639038085938,
              61.54928480379444
            ],
            [
              12.832374572753906,
              61.54535911881558
            ],
            [
              12.775554656982422,
              61.54486837329203
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
```

[This stack-overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256277/geojson-to-elasticsearch-unable-to-tessellate-shape) seems to indicate that the correct way is to split the self-intersecting polygons into several polygons so that the above polygon would be split into 2 triangles.
However the above post also uncovered a [bug in Lucene](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-9417), so we are a little confused about what to expect.

So, our question is, what is the suggested way to index self-intersecting polygons in Elasticsearch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the suggested way to index self-intersecting polygons in Elasticsearch?

You cannot index self-intersecting polygons. They need to be valid following OGC specification (http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25355).

In addition, the polygon you shared makes me wonder if there is an issue in the way you are generating those. Before splitting such a polygon into two triangles, I would try to understand why such shapes are being generated?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Great that you provided a link to the OGC spec. The elastic documentation could be clearer that OGC is the definition to use. 
I added a clarification on the source of the polygons, they are provided to us by an external source.